# numpy where implementation for this case

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `a=np.arange(0,10,1)`. I am given with another array say `b=[1,3,0]`. I need to find all the indices corresponding to location of all elements of `b` in the original array `a`. The answer in this case should be `[1,3,0]` itself. How would I do this using `np.where`. I know for one element I could do something like `np.where(a==1)`, but I want to know if there is an efficient way for an entire array of comparisons.

Comment: `where` just finds the indices of the condition array truth values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straight forward approach using `broadcasted` equality:

```
In [104]: a=np.arange(10)
In [105]: a[:,None]==[1,3,0]
Out[105]: 
array([[False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]])
In [106]: _.any(axis=1)
Out[106]: 
array([ True,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False])
In [107]: np.nonzero(_)
Out[107]: (array([0, 1, 3]),)
```

Another way to get the boolean array (a little slower for this sample):

```
In [110]: np.in1d(a,[1,3,10])
Out[110]: 
array([False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False])
```

Comment: That first solution is truely elegant - I have Never seen seen the ```None``` index comparison before, and will definitely use in the future. Can you place a reference for how it works?